# mysql how to know db's name from which i search

Tags: mysql, database, union

I have a some problems with my self-made php+sql search engine.
Can You tell me, please, how can I know database name, from which result was find?
I have a few db's, from which I'm searching using SELECT + UNION ALL + SELECT...
So I need to know from which db was string to use it in image loader as parameters.

```
$row['file']    = str_ireplace( $row['file'], '<center><A href=openfile.php?id='.$row['id'].'&base='???' target="_blank">Файл '.$row['imgno'].'</A></center>', $row['file'] );
```

Is there any possibility to realize it except adding extra row (with string like db name) in each db and using .$row['base'].  ?

UPD: And how to know the table name id DB have lot of it?

I hope it is clear.
Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the DATABASE() function will do this for you.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_database

Comment: You have to know the table name to select from it in the first place - but similar to what @Vikram said, you could do: SELECT "table1" AS table_name

Answer (score 0):

in your `SELECT + UNION ALL + SELECT` you can specify the database name:

like

```
select *, 'db1' as databasename from db1.table1
union all
select *, 'db2' as databasename from db2.table1
```